# Shared connection via network manager(via Speedify) cuts every 30-60 seconds for a few milliseconds

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I'm using a SBC (single board computer) to share network connection to my PC via network manager. The SBC is running Speedify to merge multiple internet connections and for sharing it uses network manager. I currently only have one connection in Speedify which is my home ethernet. Speedify stays connected the whole time

Roughly around every 30-60 seconds my PC seems to loose internet connection for less than 1 second.

I notice this as I see a chat I'm using having to reconnect and also when viewing livestreams it freezes briefly every 30-60 seconds for a seconds or less.

Also when I'm SSH'd into the SBC I notice a short freeze around every 30-60 seconds as well when I'm mid typing. Pings to it never drop though

When running a constant ping to 8.8.8.8 this never drops a single ping either, neither on the PC nor on the SBC.

Every once in a while on the PC (but not when the freezes happen) I see a ping reply from the SBC instead of 8.8.8.8. Not sure if that's related? around 3 pings later, the SBC ping times out, then picks back up.

Not really sure what to do here, any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that mentions any Ubuntu product. This question as written seems to be off topic.

Comment: I haven't mentioned it, but the SBC is running Ubuntu Core

Comment: Would be a good idea to EDIT the question and add that important detail.

Comment: `ping` doesn't show pongs from other hosts. If ICMP (ping/tracerout/mtr) packages works fine (odd) might be a DNS issue. Check logs/journalctl, `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service`.